# Retrieving weekday name from an integer in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert a column of a dataframe containing weekday integers into its corresponding weekday name. So 0 should become Monday, 1 Tuesday and so forth.

I have tried to convert the integers into a datetime format but it does not work. What is the best way to go about it?

```
data = {'weekday_number': [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['weekday_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weekday_number']).dt.strftime('%A')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#date-objects) objects to do the conversion, by using your weekday number as a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#timedelta-objects) from a date which is a Monday:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

data = {'weekday_number': [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['weekday_name'] = df['weekday_number'].apply(lambda w:(date(2021, 2, 1) + timedelta(days = w)).strftime('%A'))

print(df)
```

Output

```
    weekday_number weekday_name
0                1      Tuesday
1                2    Wednesday
2                0       Monday
3                3     Thursday
4                4       Friday
5                5     Saturday
6                6       Sunday
7                3     Thursday
8                2    Wednesday
9                5     Saturday
10               4       Friday
11               5     Saturday
```

You can also use the [`day_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html?highlight=calendar%20day_name#calendar.day_name) array from `calendar`:

```py
from calendar import day_name

df['weekday_name'] = df['weekday_number'].apply(lambda w:day_name[w])
```

Or using `map` with `day_name`, converting the array into a dict:

```py
df['weekday_name'] = df['weekday_number'].map(dict(enumerate(day_name)))
```

The results are the same as shown above.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for that.
First, create a dictionary for mapping days with their numbers

```
days = {0:'Monday', 1:'Tuesday', 2:'Wednesday', 3:'Thursday', 4:'Friday', 5:'Saturday', 6:'Sunday'}
```

then

```
df['weekday_name'] = df['weekday_number'].map(days)
```

Comment: nice use of `map` you could do `df['weekday_int'].map(dict(enumerate([x.strftime('%A') for x in pd.date_range('1 Feb 2021', '7 Feb 2021')])))` to avoid creating the weekdays manually, although its not such a big effort

Answer (score 0):

Without a library, you would be best of programming it on a case-by-case basis:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if(array[i] == 0):
        array[i] = "Monday"
    elif(array[i] == 1):
        array[i] = "Tuesday"
    ...
```

You can also use the calendar module.

```
import calendar
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = calendar.day_name[array[i]]
```